# A good web resource for learning Direct Compute?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, parallel-processing, scientific-computing

I am interested in getting my hands dirty with numeric computation using Microsoft's Direct Compute framework. 
The whole concept seems to be a rather poorly documented business. Are there any useful resources, such as web-tutorials or ebooks where I can learn to use this framework?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Check out the DirectCompute Lecture series, that should get you started.

http://channel9.msdn.com/tags/DirectCompute-Lecture-Series/